# Returning different queries together as a JSON object vs. multiple queries

Tags: postgresql, express, postgresql-10, pg-promise

I need to run several unrelated queries in order to render a page.

Until now I've been converting each query result as a JSON object before returning them together with something of the form:

```
SELECT (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(Q1)), (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(Q2))
```

...thus producing a row with one query result per column.

However those queries share conceptually nothing other than being required together by the end-application. In addition, calling `array_to_json` and `array_agg` produces an overhead that seems counter-intuitive to the database logic.

I am considering splitting the queries and using `pg-promise`'s `db.batch` inside `db.task` to share the same connection between the queries.

Are there caveats using this method compared to the first? What would be best performance-wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best, performance-wise, to execute multiple unrelated queries that return data via a single multi-query string, as a single transaction/atomic block.

Module [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) has method method [multi](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multi) specially for that. And if you need to pass in formatting parameters, you can either pass them in as usual variables, covering indexes/names of all queries this time, or you can supply formatting parameters separately for each query, with the help of flexible helper  [helpers.concat](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.concat) to produce the final multi-query string in a single command:

```
const queries = [
    {query: 'SELECT ...', values: ...},
    {query: 'SELECT ...', values: ...},
    {query: 'SELECT ...', values: ...}
    ...
];

const q = ()=> pgp.helpers.concat(queries);

db.multi(q)
    .then(([data1, data2, data3]) => {...})
    .catch(error => {...})
```

Note that we define `q` as a function, so the formatting-related errors are encapsulated by the query method, and processed within the `.catch`.

Comment: Thanks for your support. After some testing it would appear that the method combining JSON results is somehow faster. It takes 15.719ms compared with 35.497ms using `multi`/`spread`. I am guessing the difference is due to a combination of caching and Postgres's planner taking advantage of the single query (although the queries are unrelated per se, they do have tables in common). I will run an EXPLAIN ANALYZE and get back with further information asap.

Comment: @Kathandrax A single query is usually faster than a multi-query, due to optimizations performed by the SQL execution planner.